# Change class of all ancestor li elements with PHP DOMDocument

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I have nested bullet lists of ul > li > ul > li, etc.

```
<ul>
    <li>Mammals
        <ul>
            <li>Canine
                <ul>
                    <li>Fox</li>
                    <li>Wolf</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Feline</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Fish</li>
</ul>
```

How can I apply a class to *all* "li" elements (recursively) which are ancestors of the target element? I have:

```
<?php
$list = ob_get_clean();
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($list);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//li');
foreach ($nodes as $object) {
    $parts = parse_url($object->nodeValue);
    parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
    if (true) {
        //if certain requirements are met, modify the current object
    }
    //also modify all ancestor li elements
    //$object-> ?? ->setAttribute('class', 'current');
}
?>
```

There are reasons that the target objects must be identified before searching through each ones' ancestors. I just stripped this code down for relevancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work up the chain of parent nodes, altering those which are `li` nodes:

```
<?php

$parentNode = $node->parentNode; // ul

while ($parentNode = $parentNode->parentNode) {
    if ($parentNode->nodeName == 'LI') {
        $parentNode->setAttribute('class', 'current');
    }
}
```